# Give a stream of numbers in scheme I need to print n numbers separated by comma like (1, 2, 3, 4, ..)

Tags: printing, stream, scheme

I can print n-numbers as list with this code below:

```
(define (print-first-n stream1 n)
  (cond((= n 0) '())
      (else(cons(stream-car stream1) (print-first-n (stream-cdr stream1) (- n 1))))))
```

But I have no idea about how to add commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't print a comma in a normal list, but we can build a string with the contents of the stream, separated by commas. This will work, assuming that the string contains *numbers*:

```
(define (print-first-n stream1 n)
  (cond ((= n 1)
         (number->string (stream-car stream1)))
        (else
         (string-append
          (number->string (stream-car stream1)) ", "
          (print-first-n  (stream-cdr stream1) (- n 1))))))
```

The above solution is fine for a small value of `n`, but terribly inefficient for large values (lots of temporary strings will be created, with `O(n^2)` complexity for the append operation). For a more efficient implementation, consider using SRFI-13's concatenation procedures, like this:

```
(require srfi/13)

(define (print-first-n stream1 n)
  (let loop ((strm stream1) (n n) (acc '()))
    (if (= n 1)
        (string-concatenate-reverse
         (cons (number->string (stream-car strm)) acc))
        (loop (stream-cdr strm)
              (sub1 n)
              (list* ", " (number->string (stream-car strm)) acc)))))
```

Either way: let's say that `integers` is an infinite stream of integers starting at `1`, this is how it would look:

```
(print-first-n integers 5)
=> "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

If the stream contains some other data type, use the appropriate procedure to convert each element to a string.

Comment: Is that number->string is for the conversion of the number form the stream to string

Comment: @sageArt: that's right! if your stream contains a different type of elements, find and use the corresponding procedure to convert it to a string.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young fair enough, I updated my answer :) . But `string-append` is easier to use for a beginner, it's the way to do a natural recursion when building a string. If efficiency is of concern I agree with you. I wonder, using `(apply string-append acc)` would be alright, or `string-concatenate` is always a better option?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `(apply string-append acc)` is fine for Scheme implementations (like Racket, IIRC) that accept very large lists for `apply`. `string-concatenate` is the internal loop used by `string-append`, essentially.

Answer (score 2):

If your function just *prints* the stream contents, and doesn't need to build a string (like Óscar's answer), here's my take on it (uses [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) streams):

```
(define (print-first-n stream n)
  (stream-for-each (lambda (delim item)
                     (display delim)
                     (display item))
                   (stream-cons "" (stream-constant ", "))
                   (stream-take n stream)))
```

Example:

```
> (define natural (stream-cons 1 (stream-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) natural)))
> (print-first-n natural 10)
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

---

To output to a string (like Óscar's answer), just wrap the whole thing in a string port:

```
(define (print-first-n stream n)
  (call-with-output-string
   (lambda (out)
     (stream-for-each (lambda (delim item)
                        (display delim out)
                        (display item out))
                      (stream-cons "" (stream-constant ", "))
                      (stream-take n stream)))))
```